# How can I configure system not respond to ICMPv6 echo requests sent to a broadcast address

Tags: ipv6, ping, ifconfig, sysctl

I am attempting it by using echo command and it gives me the below error

```
+++++++++++++
t040ml000002:/proc/sys/net/ipv4 # echo “1” > /proc/sys/net/ipv6/icmp_echo_ignore_all
-bash: /proc/sys/net/ipv6/icmp_echo_ignore_all: No such file or directory
+++++++++++++
```

How can I configure it?

Comment: What kind of router are you using that still allows people to ping the broadcast address?

Comment: This may be a better approach - http://superuser.com/questions/454545/deny-ping-response-in-ipv6

Comment: That sysctl variable is only for IPv4.

Comment: IPv6 doesn't have a broadcast address...

Comment: Your code is using "smart quotes". Is that a consequence of your web browser or are they actually what you typed in your shell? You must only use `'` or `"`, definitely not `“` or `”`.

Answer (score 2):

```
sysctl net.ipv6.icmp.echo_ignore_all=1
```

Working on linux kernel 4.19.

Comment: It's just confusing, that they changed it for IPv6, as for IPv4 it's `_` instead if `.` between `icmp` and `echo`. 
`net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all` vs `net.ipv6.icmp.echo_ignore_all`

Answer (score 2):

You have the path name wrong. It is

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/icmp/echo_ignore_all
```

not

```
/proc/sys/net/ipv6/icmp_echo_ignore_all
```

Note that after the `icmp` there is a `/`, not a `_`.